# Image upload Reactjs with Laravel PHP

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel-5.8

I am using the following tool [react-images-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-upload)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ImageUploader from "react-images-upload";

const App = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(image[0]);
    axios
      .post(
        "http://192.168.1.6:8001/api/upload",
        { image: image[0] },
        {
          headers: headers,
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ImageUploader
        withIcon={true}
        singleImage={true}
        onChange={(p) => setImage(p.concat(p))}
        imgExtension={[".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg"]}
        maxFileSize={4242880}
        withPreview={true}
        withIcon={true}
        className="text-center"
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image]

And in php code:-

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {
         
         return response()->json($request->all());    
    }
```

In php the value of $request->all() is not showing the file sent in react request:-
[image]

What is the proper way to send the request with file/image to php backend ?

Answer (score 0):

Run With Below Command:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ImageUploader from "react-images-upload";

const headers = {
  Accept: "application/json", "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575",
}
const App = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(image[0]);
    axios
      .post(
        "http://192.168.1.6:8001/api/upload",
        { image: image[0] },
        {
          headers: headers,
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ImageUploader
        withIcon={true}
        singleImage={true}
        onChange={(p) => setImage(p.concat(p))}
        imgExtension={[".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".jpeg"]}
        maxFileSize={4242880}
        withPreview={true}
        withIcon={true}
        className="text-center"
      />
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You are actually missing Headers "multipart/form-data"

Comment: I tried, not got error in api response >Warning</b>:  Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST data in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0

Comment: "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------974767299852498929531610575" 

Add this type of boundary value

Comment: Solved by using  var bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.append("image", image[0]); then in request body bodyFormData , axios will automatically detect the content-type no need to manually configure, please update your answer with adding these line